# Can a flying character can use Ant Haul to carry another character?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, flight, encumbrance, oracle

One of my player is a level 8 [Oracle of Flame](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/mysteries/paizo-oracle-mysteries/flame) and she has the revelation Wings of Fire.
She is not strong enough to lift someone while flying. She would like to. She plays a Peri Aasimar with a strong angelic savior behavior.

[image: Angel carrying people]

As an Oracle, she could learn [Ant Haul](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/ant-haul/).

> The target’s carrying capacity triples. This does not affect the creature’s actual Strength in any way, merely the amount of material it can carry while benefiting from this spell. It also has no effect on encumbrance due to armor. If the creature wears armor it still takes the normal penalties for doing so regardless of how much weight the spell allows it to carry.

As DM, I plan to allow it. Now, I would like to know if it not a big deal if I consider that the *amount of material* includes a living being.

Comment: [A similar question but about a magic item.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62559/8610)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Nice read! It is indeed a similar question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes, they can

[Ant Haul](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/ant-haul/) says that *"the target’s carrying capacity triples"*, meaning that her [carrying capacity](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alignment-description/carrying-capacity/), assuming that if it's triple is enough to carry all their gear plus the carried creature and *their* gear too, shouldn't be affected by the fact that she is flying, other than reducing her speed and increasing her *armor check penalty*.

If three times her carrying capacity is still not enough to put her under *Heavy Load*, then she cannot freely move while carrying that weight, and should probably fall (*GM Fiat*) or *drag* the creature at 5 feet per round (see *Lifting and Dragging*). If she has 10 Str for instance, her maximum load is 100 lbs (~45Kg), or 300 lbs (~136Kg) under *Ant Haul*, which should be enough to carry someone else.